# The lable doesn't change in real time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a loop that changes `label8`. And I want my `label8` to change in real time but I get just the last value. How do I do that? Do I need parallel threads?

This is the code that changes the label:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal C = 35;
    label8.Text = ":";

    while (true)
    {
        C -= Convert.ToDecimal(0.01);
        label8.Text = Convert.ToString(C);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);

    }
}
```

Comment: When you use `Thread.Sleep`, you put the UI thread to sleep, so you will never see any update. Use a BackgroundWorker, a System.Windows.Forms.Timer or even a Task

Comment: Forget threading etc unless you actually have a workload to do! - Changes in the UI will best be enforced by doing a Refresh on the control.

Comment: @TaW A refresh every 200ms sounds like a huge waste of CPU time

Comment: No it doesn't. Refreshing a Label 5 timer per second is cheap and if he wants it why not? And what would be the alternative? None of what you suggest. - Of course any change the user can't follow is a waste..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because WinForm UI implemented by using a mssage loop that updates the controllers and run on a special thread called **"UI Thread"**.

The MessageLoop is responsible of calling all the Events callback you registered to. There is an excellent post by [Stephan Toub](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/profile/Stephen+Toub+-+MSFT) on this topic [Await, and UI, and deadlocks! Oh my!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-and-ui-and-deadlocks-oh-my/)

In your case, The event message loop called `Form1_Shown` and run it using the UI Thread. In the middle of the run you **ordered** the current thread (which is the UI Thread and responsible for updated) to go to sleep. and then you resume it works with more work until your loop ends.
You never actually freed the UI Thread to do some other work other then yours. (Which some of those works are getting notifications of the Label.Text you wanted to update)

Putting threads to sleep is in vast majority a bad design or lack of understanding.

You may wanted to put a delay, which actually freeing the thread for other activities, but you didn't know how to do so, so instead you put it to sleep.

You may wanted something like that

```
private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) // Notice the 'async'
{
    decimal C = 35;

    label8.Text = ":";
    while (true)
    {
        C -= Convert.ToDecimal(0.01);
        label8.Text = Convert.ToString(C);
        await Task.Delay(200); // Notice the 'await'
    }
}
```